# How can I create a if using the value of select?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

Hello I have the following code :

```
<select name="test1" class="form-control">
                <option value=""></option>
                {%  for test in tests %}
                    <option value="{{ test.id }}">{{ test.name }}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
```

Then I want to do something like this ;

```
{%  if test.id %} 

# show something but I need to know if there is sometinh in test.id
# I think the problem comes from this line, in fact I want this condition is realised if test.id is not empty else the condition is not realised.

{% endif %}
```

How can I do this ?

Comment: maybe you need this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29451208/set-default-value-for-select-html-element-in-jinja-template

Comment: No it does not work :/

Comment: Try with `{% if test.id is not None %}`

Answer (score 0):

See if this approach can help.

```
<select name="test1" class="form-control">
                <option value=""></option>
                {%  for test in tests %}
                    <option value="{{ test.id }}">{{ test.name }}</option>
                  {%  if test.id %} 
                    #show what you want..
                   {% empty %} <<<<======
                    #if empty do this...
                  {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
```

Just an example:

```
import Http Response from django 
from django.shortcuts import render 

#create a function 

def your_view(request): 
    # create a dictionary 
    context = { 
    #enter code here
        "data" : [], 
    } 
    # return response 
    return render(request, "template.html", context)
```

Now in templates/template.html,

```
{% for i in data %} 
    <div class="row"> 
        {{ i }} 
    </div> 
    {% empty %} 
    <h4>There is nothing in this list</h4> 
{% endfor %}
```

You can have a better look at this link:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/for-empty-loop-django-template-tags/