# How can I get the value of my select using Django into html?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

Hello I have this code :

```
<select name="test1" class="form-control">
            <option value=""></option>
            {%  for test in tests %}
                <option value="{{ test.id }}">{{ test.name }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
```

I would like to know how can I do to get the value of my select using django I mean I would like to have someting

```
{{ value_selected }}
```

Thank you very much

Comment: Of a submitted form? You can access it with `request.GET['test1']` (or `request.POST['test1']` if it is a POST request).

Comment: How is this different to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62873299/how-can-i-create-a-if-using-the-value-of-select) you asked an hour ago?

Answer (score 0):

When you submit the form the value will move to the function. When you render you can pass the value as a parameter.

For eg: you can write a function

```
  value_selected(request) 
  Valueselected = request.POST.["test1"] 
  Return render(request, "pg.html" {"value_selected":Valueselected})
```