# How to get select tag value in flask

Tags: python, html, flask

I have a total of two python scripts. One for the flask itself, and another for backend calculations. And I have an HTML file.

In backend.py:

```
def get_country():
    county_name = ["Bangladesh", "India", "USA"]
    country_default = "Bangladesh"
    return country_name, country_default
```

In flask_app.py:

```
import backend   
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__) 
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def home():
        country_name, country_default = backend.get_country()
        return render_template("index.html", country=county_name, default=country_default)
```

In index.html:

```
<form action="" class="form-text" method="GET">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-10">
            <select name="select_country" class="form-select form-select-lg mb-3" aria-label=".form-select-lg example">
                {% for country in country %}
                <option value="{{country}}">{{country}}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Select</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<p>You have selected {{default}}</p>
```

The questions I have here are:

1. How can I make the select tag in the HTML file to select the `default`
   value initially?
2. How can I submit the select tag value in the html file and update the
   `country_default` variable in the backend.py?

Comment: About backend https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32019733/getting-value-from-select-tag-using-flask

About HTML: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29451208/set-default-value-for-select-html-element-in-jinja-template

Comment: Thank you. I have seen this solution. It gives the solution for getting the selected value in the 'flask.py' script. But, I need to take the selected value in the 'backend.py' script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answers to your questions:**

1. You can declare the first option to be the default value using the `selected` attribute in the option tag. Then, you should remove the default value from the `country_name`.
2. You can submit the select tag in 2 ways, either using GET Method or POST Method.

**Your index.html should looks like this:**

```
<form action="/" class="form-text" method="GET/POST (Choose One)">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-10">
            <select name="select_country" class="form-select form-select-lg mb-3" aria-label=".form-select-lg example">
                <option value="{{default}}" selected>{{default}}</option>
                {% for country in country %}
                <option value="{{country}}">{{country}}</option>
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary">Select</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<p>You have selected {{default}}</p>
```

**Your backend.py should looks like this:**

```py
def get_country(default):
    county_name = ["Bangladesh", "India", "USA"]
    country_default = "Bangladesh"
    if default in country_name:
        country_default = default
    country_name.remove(country_default)
    return country_name, country_default
```

If you use **GET Method**, then it will redirect you to the "/" route with a query parameter (select_country). The route might look like this, `"/select_country=(value_selected)"`. You can get the query parameter in flask using `request.args.get(query_name)`. Your flask_app.py should look like this:

```
from backend import get_country
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__) 

@app.route('/')
def home():
    country_name, country_default = get_country(request.args.get("select_country"))
    return render_template("index.html", country=county_name, default=country_default)
```

If you use **POST Method**, then it won't change the route. Therefore there wouldn't be any query parameters. You should instead use `requests.form.get(name)` to get the posted data. Your flask_app.py should look like this:

```
from backend import get_country
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__) 

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    country_name, country_default = get_country(request.form.get("select_country"))
    return render_template("index.html", country=county_name, default=country_default)
```

Comment: Thank You. It is working. However, I need to take the selected country value back to the backend.py script for some additional calculation. Also, I have to keep that default country variable there. Any idea how can I do that? I am new to the flask. Trying to learn by doing things. Help is very much appreciated.

Comment: If you want to keep the default country variable in the backend.py, consider using a database (MySQL, SQLite, ...), or else every time you close the application the default country will be back to "Bangladesh". And you should modify backend.py.